# PyQt5 is QTimer running in separate thread and is it blocking?

Tags: pyqt5

I'm having an app which uses a database. I want to set a timer to launch a function which will modify the db periodically. But I want to be sure that it is blocking, so no read-write operations with db until this function would finish.

My QTimer is in the GUI thread, so as far as I understand, it's slot will block main thread. Am I right?

```
    class AppLauncher(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, AppWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(AppLauncher, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)
            flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            self.setWindowFlags(flags)
            self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowFullScreen)

            self.fooTimer = QTimer(self)
            self.fooTimer.timeout.connect(self.foo)

        def foo(self):
            pass

    def main():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        form = AppLauncher()
        form.show()
        app.exec_()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTimer is always running in the thread it was created and started, but that doesn't matter, as it wouldn't change the resulting behavior of the `timeout` connected functions even if it was executed in another thread.

What always matters is the thread in which the slot/function is, and as long as `foo` is a member of an instance that is in the same thread of any other function you want to "block", it will work as expected, preventing execution of anything else until it returns.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm curious now - how can QTimer call function in the main thread from another?

Comment: @Dmitry just like any other QObject, using signals. Qt uses [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) to know if the sender (the object that emits the signal) and the receiver (the object the function is a member of) live in the same thread. If they are not, the signal is *queued* and the function is executed in the thread of the target.